# ¿Cómo capturar un Shift + Tab en un Input en Angular4?

Tags: typescript, angular

Tengo varios `input`, estoy intentando capturar dentro de los mismos cuando se produce un `Tab` inverso (salto al input anterior) que se hace presionando `Shift + Tab`.

El siguiente código que captura cuando se presiona `Tab` funciona

```
<input type="text" (keydown.Tab)="_handleTab($event)">
```

Pero los siguientes no capturan el Shift+Tab

```
(keydown.Shift.Tab)="_handleTab($event)"
(keydown.shift.tab)="_handleTab($event)"
```

Segun un articulo que encontre [Angular Quick Tip: Binding Specific Keys to the Keyup and Keydown Events](https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/) se supone que funcionaria esto ultimo pero no es asi.

Comment: segun entiendo esa documentacion, el primer evento que esta en el input deberia tener keydown.shift y cuando eso pase llamas al segundo evento de verificar solo el tab , parece ser que eso no lo estas haciendo

Comment: Abajo en la seccion **key combinations** sugiere que se pueden hacer cosas como `<input (keydown.shift.esc)="...">` pero para shift+tab no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que funciona de momento es

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="_handleTab($event)">
```

y en la funcion `_handleTab`:

```
_handleTab(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === 'Tab') { // se pulso tab
         if (event.shiftKey) { // tambien se pulso conjuntamente shift
             // hacer algo
         }
    }
}
```

Aclaro probé las alternativas de leer `(keydown.Tab)="..."` pero solo reconocia cuando presionaba únicamente `Tab` sin que se produzca el evento si se presionaba conjuntamente `Shift + Tab`, lo mismo ocurrió pero a la inversa cuando hice `(keydown.shift)="..."`